# Tailoring the output of YQL

Tags: html, yql

This YQL statement ([execute in the YQL console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20content%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A//www.themoviedb.org/movie/27205%22%20and%20xpath%3D%27//h3%5B@id%3D%22year%22%5D%7C//h2%5B@id%3D%22title%22%5D/a%27)) picks out the name and year of a film from the TMDB website.

```
select content from html where url="http://www.themoviedb.org/movie/27205" and xpath='//h3[@id="year"]|//h2[@id="title"]/a'
```

the results come back like this:

```
"results": {
  "a": "Inception",
  "h3": "(2010)"
}
```

Is there any easy way to have label the results as 'name' and 'year' rather than the html elements they were grabbed from?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no **easy** way to quickly alias the returned labels. The best way at the moment is to create a custom [data table](http://datatables.org/) which makes your query to TMDB and transforms the result (with Javascript, in an [`<execute>`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-execute-chapter.html) block) to whatever you want it to be.

For example, I created a quick custom table for you which returns the results with your labels of choice (`name` and `year`). It also removes the parentheses from around the year. To give it a test run, use:

```
use "store://github.com/tmdb-jp" as tmdb;
select * from tmdb where movieid="27205"
```

With the resulting JSON having the following structure (within the usual YQL response):

```
"movie": {
 "title": "Inception",
 "year": "2010"
}
```

---

If you want to have a go at creating a data table yourself, or just see what's involved, then the source is on [my github](http://github.com/salathe/yql-tables/raw/examples/tmdb/jp.xml). Also (it might be useful) you can query for multiple movies at once:

```
use "store://github.com/tmdb-jp" as tmdb;
select * from tmdb where movieid in ("27205","9802")
```

<sup>P.S. The `store://` URLs just mean that the data table is being stored in Yahoo!'s "cloud" for speed and reliability. You can of course use a normal `http://` URL (e.g. by github one) instead.</sup>

Comment: You are a **hero**! A perfect answer with examples and explanations — nothing more could be asked for — thank you!